How to Maintain Degree Symbol and Subscript Positioning
When thermodynamic quantities refer to the standard state, it is common to typeset them with the degree symbol. For instance, as a luaLaTeX user with unicode-math, I can easily type the readable expression: $Δ_r H°$. However, when a subscript is needed for the quantity, things become more complicated. I want the subscript to appear below the degree symbol (as achieved with my \kern hack), regardless of the order in which the ° symbol and the subscript are entered:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$Δ_r H° = Δ_r H°_1 = Δ_r H_1° = Δ_r H_1\kern-4pt°$
\end{document}


Would you have a solution that provides the same flexibility in input and readability while maintaining the positioning of the degree symbol and any potential subscript, all while automating the process?

Could you live with replacing ° with ^{\circ}?

@Mico Well, I could but the point here is trying not to use ^{\circ} (for readability et effectiveness).

You could redefine ° as ^{\circ}:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{°}{^{\circ}}
\begin{document}
$Δ_r H° = Δ_r H°_1 = Δ_r H_1° = Δ_r H_1\kern-4pt°$
\end{document}


Note that this means you cannot use ° anymore outside of math.

Nice. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.
